# GWT - onModuleLoad() not being called

Tags: java, gwt

In my project html file, I have:

```
<div id="flightList"></div>
```

And in my projectname.java file, I have:

```
@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {
    ...
    OtherClass.load1();
}
```

Which calls this method (in another class):

```
public static void load1() {
    ...
    RootPanel.get("flightList").add(OriginalClass.getMainPanel());
}
```

where `mainPanel` was updated earlier in the `load1` method.

For some reason, however, onModuleLoad is never called when I run the web app. I verify this with a println() statement before the call to load1(), which is never printed.

Comment: What else is in the onModuleLoad method? What is in your module file (.gwt.xml)? Any messages in either the console or the dev mode log?

Comment: I have `@RemoveServiceRelativePath` annotations on my Services in the client package. For my web.xml file, I only have the welcome page, which loads (the HTML part of it, not the module), but then gives a 404 error when the module does load. If I add servlets and servlet-mappings to web.xml I get a "HTML file not found" error.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it. It was something wrong with my web.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

There is not one problem associated with it. I think the GWT plugin here plays foul. 
My suggestion is to install very old version of chrome [Old Version 10.06](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/download/google-chrome-10-0-648-127-1). Run the Module as usual but in super-dev mode. If console shows error which in my case, was to inherit new libraries *(if you are using any)* in *.gwt.xml file. 
Another error which you may encounter is to include `<set-configuration-property name='xsiframe.failIfScriptTag' value='FALSE'/>` again in *.gwt.xml.

After these tweaks application would run as it should.